# Django Template. How to iterate two contexts {% for a, b in c,d %}

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to iterate over two contexts that coming from my 2 views.
How to iterate two contexts in django template for example

```
{% for parent, child in all_parents, all_childs %}
```

My view file is:

```
class NodeListView(generic.ListView):
    model = BackendNodes
    context_object_name = 'all_childs'

class BackendModulesListView(generic.ListView):
    context_object_name = 'all_parents'
    model = BackendModule
```

But django does not allow write such code.
So is there any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zip` the two iterators before passing them to the template rendering engine:

```
{% for parent, child in parents_and_childs %}
```

where

```
parents_and_childs = zip(all_parents, all_childs)
```

## Update

You can [provide the context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context) manually (I'm guessing here what your actual *parents* and *children* should be):

```
class SomeViewUsingBoth:
    template_name = '...'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        return {
            'parents_and_childs': zip(BackendModule.objects.all(),
                                      BackendNodes.objects.all())
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but where to `zip` context_object_names?

Comment: @Ostin You manually need to provide the context in this case. This can be done for example by defining `get_context_data` on the view. Does [this part of the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context) help?

Comment: I am new to python explain me in detail please